# async method doesn't seem to await in stream

Tags: flutter

I'm wondering if anyone can help me with my authentication bloc. I'm getting an intermittent error. Basically routing in my app depends on the `newUser`  returned from `SharedPreferences` . In the code the state returned depends on the logic in `_mapAuthenticationUserChangedToState`. However sometimes the event doesn't read from SP "quick enough" and the routing is wrong. Even when the routing works... I can see from logging that the app, even when the routing is correct, that `initState` of the screen it shouldn't route to gets called. Is there anything obvious in my code that I'm doing wrong. ..(Could be also writing to SP isn't quick enough I'm my social login flow)

```
class AuthenticationBloc extends Bloc<AuthenticationEvent, AuthenticationState> {
      AuthenticationBloc({
        @required AuthenticationRepository authenticationRepository,
      })  : assert(authenticationRepository != null),
            _authenticationRepository = authenticationRepository,
            super(const AuthenticationState.unknown()) {
        _userSubscription = _authenticationRepository.user.listen(
          (user) => add(AuthenticationUserChanged(user, user.isNewUser)),
        );
      }
    
      final AuthenticationRepository _authenticationRepository;
      StreamSubscription<PraxUser> _userSubscription;
    
      @override
      Stream<AuthenticationState> mapEventToState(
        AuthenticationEvent event,
      ) async* {
        if (event is AuthenticationUserChanged) {
          var userRepository = UserRepository();
          final DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfoPlugin = new DeviceInfoPlugin();
          SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    
          bool isNewUser = prefs.getBool('is_new_user') ?? false;
    
          yield _mapAuthenticationUserChangedToState(event, isNewUser);
        } else if (event is AuthenticationLogoutRequested) {
          unawaited(_authenticationRepository.logOut());
        }
      }
    
      @override
      Future<void> close() {
        _userSubscription?.cancel();
        return super.close();
      }
    
      AuthenticationState _mapAuthenticationUserChangedToState(
        AuthenticationUserChanged event,
        bool isNewUser,
      ) {
        if (event.user != PraxUser.empty) {
          if (isNewUser) {
            return AuthenticationState.signedUp(event.user);
          } else {
            return AuthenticationState.authenticated(event.user);
          }
        } else {
          return AuthenticationState.unauthenticated();
        }
      }
    }
```

EDIT:

```
else if (state is SignUpSuccess) {
                    Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
                    BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationBloc>(context).add(AuthenticationUserChanged(state.user, true));
                  } else if (state is AlreadySignedUpSuccess) {
                    Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
                    BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationBloc>(context).add(AuthenticationUserChanged(state.user, false));
```

EDIT:

my main.dart has a listener

```
return BlocListener<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
          listener: (context, state) {
            final id = state.user.id;

            switch (state.status) {
              case AuthenticationStatus.signedUp:
                _navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil<void>(
                  AppRouter.onboarding,
                  (route) => false,
                );
                break;
              case AuthenticationStatus.authenticated:
                _navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil<void>(
                  AppRouter.home,
                  (route) => false,
                );
                break;
              case AuthenticationStatus.unauthenticated:
                _navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil<void>(
                  AppRouter.intro,
                  (route) => false,
                );
                break;
              default:
                break;
            }
```

Comment: how do you know that reading SP is not "quick enough"? with event based streams it can take even 10 seconds and everything should work just fine since `mapEventToState` will ultimately yield new state and this will trigger a new item in the bloc's stream

Comment: Maybe that's not where the problem lies then. I have a listener on the bloc from my sign up page. (Added above). And my feeling is that `theNewUser` variable (which ultimately controls the navigation) is not being assigned ... Because as I said I enter in to the initState of the wrong page

Comment: override `AuthenticationBloc.onEvent` and `AuthenticationBloc.onTransition` adding some logs there and also inside `listener:` callback and check how it works

Comment: cheers, I'll give that a go